# Is the smallest field of a finite set also denoted $\sigma$(.)?

Tags: notation

The collection $\{A, A^c, \emptyset, \Omega\}$ is, I think, the smallest field generated by A. Is this also denoted $\sigma$(A) or is that notation reserved for $\sigma$-fields?

Comment: The collection $\{A, A^c, \emptyset, \Omega\}$ *is* a $\sigma$-field.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks. I thought it had to be closed under countably infinite unions to be a $\sigma$-field. I guess you could union $A$ with itself infinitely many times ... is that how we get there?? Is it it also a field?

Comment: Any finite set that is closed under unions is closed under countable unions, indeed under any sized unions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila. Thank you also. What does countably infinite unions mean for a finite set such as the one above? Can I sa that if  $\cup_{i=1}^\infinty A_i$, etc., are in the set then the set is closed under countably infinite unions?

Comment: What is an infinite sequence of elements from $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila. Do you mean $\{0,1\}^\infty$. If yes then I am not getting the point.

Comment: You are asking me about a countable union of elements of a finite set. I'm asking you what would an infinite sequence be, if all the elements appearing in it come from a finite set, in this specific example, $\{0,1\}$. My point is that you're making the mistake of treating unions as somehow "exceptional" and differently than you'd treat other operations. You shouldn't.

Comment: @AsafKaragila. Okay, then what distinguishes a field from a $\sigma$-field if I can monkey around with countably infinite unions of elements of a finite collection,( per my previous comment)?

Comment: The fact that it is closed under countable unions and intersections, of course. It's the same thing that differentiates "finite" and "infinite" or "metric space" and "complete metric space", etc. Some definitions in mathematics are just vacuously true in some situations. It's a good idea to get used to that fact.

Comment: I can live with that.

Answer (score 1):

To your question: What you describe would be denoted $\sigma(\{A\})$, the smallest $\sigma$-field containing $\{A\}$ as a subset, *not* $\sigma(A)$.

Comment: Thanks for posting but now I'm a confused again -- a permanent state with me so I'm getting used to it. In the setting above  A is a subset (not an elemental)  in a collection. Why should the sigma field it generates be labelled differently?

Comment: I probably shouldn't but I will and I'll also apologize in advance for being a nuisance: "What you describe would be denoted σ({A}), the smallest σ-field containing {A} as a subset, not σ(A)" ... the smallest $\sigma$-field containing A as a ....?